# Find and replace with regex in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap-3, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 and I am wanting to shift my bootstrap2 project to bootstrap3.

How can I replace:

```
span2
```

to

```
col-lg-2
```

My pattern is

```
span[0-9]+
```

Comment: dossible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870653/sublime-text-find-and-replace-with-regex-to-convert-jquery-live-event-to-on

Comment: i wasn't aware about () in replace.. it holds the string for $ variables (e.g. $1). right?

Comment: exactly. $0 references the whole matched text, $1 the group starting with the first (not escaped) parenthesis, and so in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct, just place a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the part you want captured and then reference back to that group in your replacement.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*..

```
Find: span([0-9]+)
Replace: col-lg-$1
```

### Edit

To add a class to your input field, you can use the following:

```
Find: <input[^>]*class="\K[^"]*
Replace: form-control
```

Sublime Text 2 allows you to use the `\K` escape sequence. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

Comment: i want to add class '.form-control'
so i tried 
find: <input([\s\w="]*)class="
replace: <input $1 class="form-control

Answer (score 0):

find what: span(\d)

replace with: col-lg-$1

- (\d) matches one digit and stores it in match-group 1
- $1 inserts the match-group 1

do not forget to enable the regular expression button (".*").

your "span([0-9])" is valid as well